# Why would jQuery prependTo duplicate the element(s) I'm moving?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

tl;dr: Here is a recording of my problem where I set a breakpoint, reload the page and step through the code: http://recordit.co/uNtqr31G0e

I created this code a few weeks ago and it's been working perfectly, but after checking the website today (and messing with some unrelated owl-carousel JavaScript) any elements on our product page moved with insertAfter or prependTo are showing twice in the new location once the JavaScript executes. This was working perfectly yesterday though.

Embedded is the stripped down version of the code from the product page that I'm modifying, but the code works fine using StackOverflows code editor & Codepen.io

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var shoppingCartIcon = $('.describe-list-icon .fa-shopping-cart');
        var pricingDescribeList = shoppingCartIcon.closest('.describe-list');
        pricingDescribeList.addClass('pricing');
        pricingDescribeList.prependTo('.content');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  
</div>
<div class="describe-list">
                    <div class="describe-list-icon text-center">
                        <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="describe-list-content">
                        <p>$229.99</p>
                        <p></p><div id="book_button_partyz_id_73847" class="button_book" style="cursor:pointer; display:inline-block" onclick="if(navigator.cookieEnabled){if(typeof last_item_container_id != &quot;undefined&quot;) { document.getElementById(&quot;container_&quot; + last_item_container_id).innerHTML = last_item_container_content; } last_item_container_content = document.getElementById(&quot;container_partyz_id_73847&quot;).innerHTML; last_item_container_id = &quot;partyz_id_73847&quot;; document.getElementById(&quot;container_partyz_id_73847&quot;).innerHTML = &quot;<div id=\&quot;item_container\&quot;>&nbsp;</div>&quot;; ajax_link(&quot;item_container&quot;,&quot;store.item.calendar?root_path=&amp;responsive=1&amp;show_instructions=1&amp;show_start_form=1&amp;itemid=partyz_id_73847&quot;,&quot;post_info=1&quot;); this.style.display = &quot;none&quot;;}else{alert(&quot;Cookies are not enabled.  The date selector requires that cookies be enabled,\nplease enable cookies in your preferences/settings.&quot;);}"><nobr>Add to Cart</nobr></div><br><p></p>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Codepen Link: https://codepen.io/CodeBradley/pen/oMYzoB

The product page I'm referring to: https://partyz.ourers.com/items/dunk_tank/

The actual JavaScript:
https://files.sysers.com/cp/upload/partyz/editor/full/main.js

Comment: Please extract your `onclick` code to function, it's not readable.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman that's added by the third-party CRM I'm using and it's unrelated to this issue, as far as I know. I've tried removing it completely to see if it was related to a syntax error and it didn't change the result.

Comment: After watching your recording it looks like you are duplicating the same div. Instead of prepending you can simply write shoppingCartIcon.closest('describe-list').addClass('pricing') .

Comment: @RahulRaut That would just add the class pricing to describe-list and wouldn't move the element to where I need it in the DOM. Can you explain what line of code is duplicating the div?

Comment: So I fixed the button and I have no clue what I did (the code is now changed on the live website but that's not what fixed it, I have no clue what did) However, the same thing is happening to a div a bit further down on the page that is using insertAfter(). For some reason it's being duplicated as well and it only happens when the insertAfter() line is executed. (.row.tab-content)